# how can test and check TPS in substrate?

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

I gonna to check and test `TPS` and `bottleneck` in substrate .

what should i do for that and how can i do that in local ? please guide me for that  .

Comment: Same as in elements: What kind of TPS and what bottlenecks? How many nodes do you want? How many para-chains? What do you even want to archieve?

Comment: `What kind of TPS` , whats your mean ?

Comment: i wanna check how many percentage of cpu is using with substrate . 

2 nodes .

i wanna test it in local substrate ,

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi , I wanna do some Test like this : https://hackmd.io/@cp287/Bk1kx2x4U